# Problema con Expresión Regular al Separar Variables que Están Unidas

Tags: java, regex

Estoy intento crear una expresión regular que me extraiga variables entre llaves de un texto, el proceso funciona bien si las variables están separadas, pero al esta juntas mi expresión regular ya no las extrae individualmente, he probado multiples expresiones pero no logro que funcione correctamente.

Este seria un ejemplo simple de lo que estoy haciendo:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexVariables {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\{\\S+})");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Prueba {p-variable1}{p-variable2}  {p-variable3}:{p-variable4} {p-variable1}");

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

La salida que produce el código es:

```
{p-variable1}{p-variable2}
{p-variable3}:{p-variable4}
{p-variable1}
```

Lo que busco seria:

```
p-variable1
p-variable2
p-variable3
p-variable4
```

Comment: Estoy probando con `"\\{(\\S+?)\\}"` (el interrogante hace que pare antes, haciendo el grupo *ungreedy*), pero no acabo de entender por qué mantiene las llaves, si están fuera del grupo

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario me has dado una base para continuar porque no tenia claro lo del interrogante, basándome en lo que mencionas llegue a este regex "(?<=\\{).+?(?=\\})".

Comment: Podrías utilizar "\\{(.*?)\\}" y en el println agregar group(1)

Comment: @FrancoBerardi que buena solución considero que tu propuesta es mejor que la que estaba utilizando, si lo puedes tomarte el tiempo para colocarla como respuesta para poder marcarla.

Comment: Done! Ojalá se entienda. Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución podría ser `\\{(.*?)\\}`.

Para evitar que se impriman las llaves en el while, podes utilizar la función `matcher.group(1) //el grupo 1 es (.*?), mientras que el 0 es todo - con las llaves incluidas`

Como las llaves son caracteres especiales en regex, necesitas escapearlas con el backslash `\{` para hacer el match literal.

`(.*?)` va a matchear todo hasta una llave de cierre, es decir, no sirve si el contenido va a tener más llaves de cierre.

Por último, para imprimir los resultados únicos:

```
matcher.results()
            .map(mr -> mr.group(1))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()).forEach(m -> System.out.println(m));
//p-variable1
//p-variable2
//p-variable3
//p-variable4
```

Espero te sirva!